# VS code launch config logs

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-10, vscode-debugger, launch-configuration

I am attempting to attach a remote debugger to a running debug process in the cloud.  I have a launch config as follows

```
{
            "address": "https://my.loadbalancer.url",
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "name": "Attach to Remote test aws fargate URL",
            "port": 9229,
            "remoteRoot": "/usr/src/app/",
            "request": "attach",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "type": "node"
},
```

But the debugger is not attaching.  I have confirmed that doing this same launch configuration works if I have a public IP of the remote instance in the address field, but I am trying to set it up with the url of the load balancer.  I have confirmed that hitting https://my.loadbalancer.url:9229 on my browser returns a 400 response "Websockets request expected" which means the load balancer is forwarding to the correct instance and port on my deployed container.1

VS code fails to connect the debugger, but I cannot find any log output indicating the reason for the error.  I would like to see the logs to be able to troubleshoot why its not connecting.  Are the logs for a failed launch config available anywhere?  I am running VS code on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the logs are in Output > Window
The issue was including the https:// in the address field of the config, looks like vs code automatically prefixes your address with http:// so I added an http listener to my load balancer at 9229.  Still not sure how to get vs code to prefix https:// instead of http://